# How to add all classes in a project to a list

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I searched the internet trying to find a solution to this problem. Read a lot about singleton and such patterns but I can't find a good solution to my particular problem (even though I think it's a pretty simple problem).

I got a solution with a lot of derived classes. What I would like is to have a list/container/something I can refer/access to/from which contains an object of each class in my solution.

So something like this:

```
public class Main
{
    public static List<Operation> classList;
    public Main()
    {
        initialize();
    }

    public void initialize()
    {
        classList = new List<Operation>();
        Operation operation1 = new operation1();
        Operation operation2 = new operation2();
        classList.Add(operation1);
        classList.Add(operation2);
    }
}
```

Operation class is derived from Main.

Operation1 and Operation2 class is derived from Operation class.

UPDATE:

What I would like afterwards is something like this:

```
classList[].callMethodFromClass or classList("operation1").callMethodFromClass
```

Comment: May I ask - why do you need such a container? What is the purpose of it?

Comment: You could use reflection to find the types of all the classes in all the DLLs in your output directory. You can also use reflection to instantiate an object of each type. Is this what you want to do?

Comment: where do you get the error?

Comment: Good question and a probably a thing I forgot to explain. The solution is an add-in for a program where I need to call a method from a specific class when a user hits the menubar. I need this to make sure I'm not ending up with a lot of objects when user this the menubar multiple times.
I hope I'm making myself clear enough if not I will try to explain in another way.

Comment: This seems like a classic XY Problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem .  You have a problem, and rather than ask how to solve your problem, you ask how to solve a different, more complex, and frankly rather convoluted and obtuse problem that you think solves your original problem.  There are much simpler ways of solving problems of avoiding creating too many objects.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I think you're right. Cause my actually problem isn't something about reflection, it's more about avoiding to create too many objects. So what do I do now? Do I edit this question? Do I post a new question with the original problem? Still a bit new to the programming world in general and particularly new to asking questions in this forum.

Comment: at this point, i'd delete your question and ask a new one.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need reflection for this:

```
IEnumerable<Type> derivedTypes = Assembly
    .GetAssembly(typeof(Operation))
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(type => typeof(Operation).IsAssignableFrom(type));
```

Then, for each type, you can create an instance using `Activator`:

```
Operation operation = (Operation)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

The above code assumes that all derived types reside in the same assembly as your Operation class. If they're spread across multiple assemblies, then you'll need to repeat the above process for each assembly. Also note that the Operation type itself will be included in the collection of types. If that's a problem then you need to check for it specifically.

Note that the above Activator code only works for classes that have a constructor that takes no arguments. If you have any classes that don't fit that pattern then things become more complicated. There is an overload for CreateInstance that takes an array of objects to be used as constructor arguments, but the problem is in determining what those arguments should be. That will require some knowledge about the specific class you're dealing with. In other words, you'll want to add a check for this to make sure that some class won't accidentally break your code, and you'll want to require all classes to have a constructor that conforms to a certain standard (e.g. no parameters).

Comment: As for now they're all in the same assembly. Am I right when I say that these instances are created at runtime? I want to call a method from the instances at compile time.
But none of the constructors has any parameters.

Comment: The instances will be created at run-time, yes. If you want to do something like this at compile-time... maybe with the upcoming Roslyn, or with an IL weaving tool like PostSharp or Fody. Or perhaps with T4, but that sounds like a hacky solution. ;) But why do you want to call methods at compile-time? To generate code?

Comment: Getting the error on the IEnumerable<Type> line: 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
When I think again I'm actually not sure I need to call the methods at compile time. Anyway solving the error might bring me to a solution for the problem.

Comment: That's... peculiar. Which foreach statement?

Comment: My mistake. I edited the comment of course it's not on the foreach statement cause it doesn't exists ;) It's on the IEnumerable line.

Comment: Found the problem! I'm starting the initialize() in the constructor and each time it reads the method it calls the constructor again. So recursively calling itself. Where should I run the initialize method?

Comment: You mentioned that these operations will be put in a menubar, so the code that initializes that menubar sounds like a good spot. Exactly where and how depends on how you're setting up your UI and what framework you're using. Is your system meant to support user-supplied menu actions or plugins or something like that?

Comment: It supports user-supplied menu actions. Its running on .Net framework.

Answer (score 1):

This will find all the types in the **assembly** that derive from Operation. A solution can contain more than 1 assembly, though.

```
Type baseType = typeof(Operation);
foreach (var type in typeof(Main).Assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(type => baseType.IsAssignableFrom(type))) {
        classList.Add(type);
}
```

Edit: I forgot to add instances of these types instead of the Type itself.
So you need to use

```
classList.Add((Operation)Activator.CreateInstance(type));
```

instead.

Comment: Getting the error on the foreach statement:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Found the problem! I'm starting the initialize() in the constructor and each time it reads the method it calls the constructor again. So recursively calling itself. Where should I run the initialize method?